Не могу сделать задачу, помогите пожалуйста
Препод после второй лекции по массивам задал лабораторную с написанием программы, которая должна заданные из консоли объекты линейного массива присваивать объектам двумерного массива 10 на 10 с центра по спирали, а после еще и выводить эту матрицу(это я даже не представляю как сделать). Познаниями в с++ = 0 ,наклепал что то из того что знаю. Критических ошибок код не выдает, но пишет "stack smashing detected: terminated", если поймете что я написал помогите чем сможете пожалуйста.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   char vvod[100];
    cin >> vvod;
    char spiral[10][10];
    char zapolnenie_stroka=6, zapolnenie_stolb=6, shag_vvoda=0, shag=1;

    int i=strlen(vvod);

    for(int q=0 ; q<i ; q++)
    {   for(int z=0; z<=shag; z++)
        {
            spiral[zapolnenie_stroka][zapolnenie_stolb]=vvod[shag_vvoda],zapolnenie_stroka--,shag_vvoda++;
        }
        for(int c=0; c<=shag; c++)
        {
            spiral[zapolnenie_stroka][zapolnenie_stolb]=vvod[shag_vvoda],zapolnenie_stolb--,shag_vvoda++;
        }
         shag++;
        for(int v=0; v<=shag; v++)
        {
            spiral[zapolnenie_stroka][zapolnenie_stolb]=vvod[shag_vvoda],zapolnenie_stroka++,shag_vvoda++;
        }
        for(int b=0; b<=shag; b++)
        {
            spiral[zapolnenie_stroka][zapolnenie_stolb]=vvod[shag_vvoda],zapolnenie_stolb++,shag_vvoda++;
        }
         shag++;
        
    }



    return 0;
}


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Здесь уже есть вопросы по такой задаче, поищите.

Начните проверять выход за пределы массива при каждом обращении.

Вот ещё Заполнение квадратной матрицы по спирали по часовой стрелке от центра
